# Convergence of $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^p(1+x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove that the below integral converges
$$
\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^p(1+x)}dx\\
0<p<1
$$

**Proof**:
$$
\frac{1}{x^p(1+x)}\leq\frac{1}{x^p}
$$
for $0<x\leq1$. Therefore
$$
\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^p(1+x)}dx\leq\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^p}=\frac{1}{(1-p)}\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\left(1-a^{-p+1}\right)
$$
which exists for $-p+1>0$. Therefore $p<1$ and hence the given integral converges.

**My Doubt**:
How do I know there isn't another function $g(x)$ such that $f(x)<g(x)$ in $0<x\leq1$ such that $\displaystyle \int_0^1g(x)dx$ exists? I tried finding such functions but couldn't. Yet, how do I know for sure?

**Or**

does it even matter? Is it just enough to prove that there is one function dependent on $p$ whose integral in $(0,1]$ converges? I mean, if there's *just one* function that depends on $p$ which is also happens to be greater than $f(x)$ and converges in the given interval, then obviously, $f(x)$ would also converge...right? Is that line of reasoning sound?

Comment: The factor $\dfrac1{x+1}$ is very easy to bound by constants in $[0,1]$.

Comment: You could add a few things, such as the fact that your function is greater than $0$, and also write the integral as the limit of an integral whom boundary is not $0$, such as $\int_{\epsilon}^1\frac{dx}{x^p(1+x)}dx$, with $\epsilon$ going to $0$. That would be more rigourous and not assume either of your integrals is converging.

Comment: Another function that works is $g(x)=2/x^{p}$. A third one would be $g(x)=3/x^{p}$. So there are infinitely many that work. As soon as you find one for which the comparison test is satisfied, you're done. Also, note you've shown convergence for $p<1$. The condition $p>0$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument looks good, but here is a way to formalize it. Consider the limit $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^1\frac{dx}{x^p(1+x)}$. Your argument shows that for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$\int_\epsilon^1\frac{dx}{x^p(1+x)}\le\int_\epsilon^1\frac{dx}{x^p}\le\frac1{1-p}.$$
Thus, $f(\epsilon):=\int_\epsilon^1\frac{dx}{x^p(1+x)}$ increases as $\epsilon\to 0$ (since $\frac1{x^p(1+x)}>0$) and is bounded above, so the limit (i.e., the improper integral) exists.